# Sheets - Max value from lookup column

Tags: google-sheets, max, lookup

Using Google Sheets, I have a reference sheet with names along the Header and 3 values below each.
On the primary sheet, I want to have a name input in cell B8 and a formula in C12 to take that name and lookup in sheet 'Range' for the 3 values but return the highest value of the 3.

Here is the shared sheet: [HighValueTest google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AauLcgLPKVMb3If_2cxkhjdHFwiaNldwzZP0lwSkaIY/edit?usp=sharing)

Once I have that value (between 1 and 5) I want to highlight a column of cells representing the count of that value.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure about your question. Checked out the google sheet and simply wrapping the hlookup function with max seemed to work i.e. `ArrayFormula(max(hlookup(B8,Range!B1:BD4,{2;3;4},false)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a formula to copy it down for that max values of your heroes:

```
=MAX(INDEX(Range!$B$2:$4, 0, MATCH(B8, Range!$B$1:$1, 0)))
```

[image]

And here is the formula for conditional formatting for that indicator rows (apply to the range `B2:B6`):

```
=MAX($C$21:$C$23) >= (5 - ROW() + ROW($B$2))
```

`$C$21:$C$23` here is just the range where we've put our max values before.

[image]

Comment: In reference to the conditional formatting formula, is the significance of the $2 in reference to the formatting beginning at row 2?

Comment: Sorry, I have come up against an issue if I use merged cells for the conditional highlighting. If I use `=C21 >= (5 - ROW() + ROW($K$14))` against a group of merged cells, I get a blank or two. I have added this on the sheet referred to. Any ideas of a way around that please?

Comment: We did it on your sheet.

Comment: I must apologize for messing around. I copied your working formula to my project sheet and discovered I had to offset the highlight columns to fit the task. I managed to get it working with one issue: When the default value is "0" the highlight is full at value "5" for some reason, although it isn't in your working version. I have messed up formatting or something, so have a new share of my project sheet here, if you're willing to rescue a less smart tech: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2baWk47UEe0bETOkpkUdmdRMrNOEKtSxnXcORrJPT0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Done. Do not forget to revoke access.